# Drupal: send output to user in form's submit handler, instead of redirecting

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms

I have this basic Drupal scenario and question:

I have a form which accepts some input from user, and a submit handler which should process data and show the result to user. In other words, I don't write anything in database or set e variables etc., just show some output to user.
I was wondering how I can do this, because a submit handler redirects the flow to another menu item -which the form values ($form_state) are not available anymore. Redirecting form to itself is not useful, because I just receive the raw posted inputs -not processed $form_state.

How can I prevent the redirection and just show some output to user in submit handler?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are building your form you want to set re-direct to false:

```
$form['#redirect'] = FALSE;
```

There is more on redirect here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#redirect

If I have understood your question correctly this is what you are after.

Comment: I tried to send out output by setting #redirect to false, but it didn't work as well. After reading the source of drupal, I found out that setting the value as above only redirects the the flow back to form page with fields set with user input. Still struggling with this issue.

Comment: Okay fair enough. Your best bet is to create the output in the form building function. a nice way of doing it is shown in the first comment here: http://drupal.org/node/870120. Hope this gets you going

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm. I used the $form_state['storage'] to send the result back to form function and displayed it there.